# Show that the set $S = \{ax + by : x, y ∈ \mathbb{Z} \} \cap \mathbb{N}$ is not empty

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> (a) Show that the set $S = \{ax + by : x, y ∈ \mathbb{Z} \} \cap \mathbb{N}$ is not empty.

Proof. Notice that if $ a = b = 0$, then $S = \emptyset$, so pick an $a \ne 0$. If $a$ is positive, then  $1 \cdot a+ 0 \cdot b > 0$, so $a \in S$. If $a$ is negative then $-1 \cdot a + 0 \cdot b > 0.$ Thus $S$ contains at least one element, either $a$ or $-a$, so $S$ is not empty.

> (b) Let $d$ be the least element of $S$. Show that if $d_1 \mid a $ and $d_1 \mid b$, then $d_1 \mid d$.

Proof. Suppose that $d_1 \mid a$ and $d_1 \mid b$, then $a = d_1q_1$ for some $q_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b = d_1q_2$ for some $q_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $d \in S$, it may be expressed as $d = ax + by > 0$ for some $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus $d = (d_1q_1)x + (d_1q_2)y = d_1(q_1x + q_2y), $ demonstrating that $d_1 \mid d$.

> (c) If $d \mid a $, then $d \mid b$

I think I did (a) and (b) correctly, I just need help starting (c). Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't say explicitly in the problem, but I'm assuming that $a$ and $b$ are integers.

Comment: @Regret I think $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of positive integers here.

Comment: @Kitty Yes. The $d$ in (c) is still the least element.

Comment: Since you are trying to find $\gcd(a, b)$, $a$ and $b$ are integers that are not both zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal here is to show that $d = \gcd(a, b)$, where $d$ is the least element of the set $S = \{ax + by~|~x, y \in \mathbb{N}\}$.  '

In part a, you established that $S$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{N}$, so it has a least element, $d$.  In part b, you established that if $d_1$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$, then it is a divisor of $d$. It remains to show that $d|a$ and $d|b$.

Since $a, d \in \mathbb{Z}$, there exist integers $q, r$, with $0 \leq r < d$ such that $a = qd + r$.  Since $d$ is the least element in set $S$, there exist integers $x_0$ and $y_0$ such that $d = ax_0 + by_0$.  Thus,
\begin{align*}
r & = qd - a\\
  & = q(ax_0 + by_0) - a\\
  & = (qx_0 - 1)a + by_0
\end{align*}
If $r > 0$, then $r \in S$, contradicting the fact that $d$ is the least element in $S$.  Thus, $r = 0$, so $d|a$.  By similar argument, you can show that $d|b$.

What part b establishes is that if $d_1$ is a divisor of both $a$ and $b$, then it is also a divisor of $d$.  Since $d > 0$ is a divisor of both $a$ and $b$ and $d_1 \leq d$, $d = \gcd(a, b)$.